# Validation rule looking at prior value on related object

Tags: formula, validation, account, validation-rule, record-type

*Related to my previous question: [How to make accounts read-only / locked?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/166207/40991)*

I'm trying to prevent changes from being made to accounts with a certain record type.

One possible change a user could make is to the list of related objects (e.g. its contacts). Accordingly, I'm trying to write a validation rule for these object types that prevents them from being either added to or removed from these records. I thought the following would work:

```
AND(
    OR(
        Account.RecordTypeId = "0124E0000000fKD",
        PRIORVALUE(Account.RecordTypeId) = "0124E0000000fKD"
    ),
    OR(
        ISCHANGED(AccountId),
        ISNEW()
    )
)
```

But a get a syntax error:

> The PRIORVALUE function cannot reference the Account.RecordTypeId
>   field

Some Googling reveals that others have had similar problems (e.g. [this thread](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000hOBNAA2)).

So: what's the right way to check the record type of the previously linked account?

Comment: Can you have a formula field for capturing recordtype and use it in you validation rule with PRIORVALUE function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Account` isn't being modified, so checking its *previous* value doesn't make any sense. It didn't change! Just remove that part of your formula:

```
AND(
    Account.RecordTypeId = "0124E0000000fKD",
    OR(
        ISCHANGED(AccountId),
        ISNEW()
    )
)
```

I recommend you also filter on `RecordType.DeveloperName`. It makes your validation less brittle as it should work in all your environments, and also much easier to read:

```
Account.RecordType.DeveloperName = "Some_Record_Type_You_Can_Read"
```

Comment: Ah, OK. That makes sense, but it shifts my problem. How can I detect when (e.g.) a contact was linked to an account of a certain type, but has been removed?

Comment: The `Contact` has been removed? What do you mean? Deleted? Orphaned?

Comment: Sorry Adrian - I mean moved onto another account.

Comment: That's why you have `ISCHANGED(AccountId)`.

Comment: That's half true - by combining `ISCHANGED(AccountId)` and a check on the record type of the account, I can *either* check that I'm not moving *onto* or *away* from an account with a certain type (which way round it is depends on whether `Account.RecordTypeId` hold the value from before or after the change), but not both. Does that make sense?

Comment: @TomWright The rule would need to fire on Contact, NOT Account. Only IsChanged(AccountID) would apply to the field on Contact. The recordType would apply to the Account. You won't be able to reach it from Contact; at least not easily.